# Why is my_turtle alive even after I finished it?

Tags: ros, rosnode, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am lerning ROS from scratch following this: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes

first I did:

> $ rosnode list

and the output was:

> /rosout

then I started the Turtle:

> $ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node

> $ rosnode list

and the output was:

> /rosout
>
> /turtlesim

then I killed the Turtle doing **control+C**

and started a new turtle with my custom name:

> $ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node __name:=my_turtle

bust afer calling rosnode list I see 3 turtles running, but the oldone is not there since I can not do a ping on it...
what am doing wrong?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257631/why-is-my_turtle-alive-even-after-i-finished-it?/) by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 424 on 2017-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well I've found the reason why:

the correct way (or the cleanest way) to finish the execution of a node is actually invoking the command:

> $rosnode kill <node_name>

this will gently invoke the dispose in the node which among others release resources, dispose itself and "Disconnect from the Master"-- Ha! that is very important!

Since I can terminate the application (the node is an application too) by doing **Control+ C**, I've faced the issue that this method doesn't give a chance to the node to dispose itself properly, this is the reason why the zombie node is still visible when I do:

> $rosnode list

anyways, the hole graph can be updated / cleaned and the "**zombie node**" can be removed after calling a

> $rosnode cleanup

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3